# Conditional child animations based on parent CSS state (with styled-components for React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

With [`styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) for React, are there any alternatives to something like

```
.btn:hover:not(.inactive)>.btn-top,
.btn.active:not(.inactive)>.btn-top {
  z-index: 2;
  /* transform here */
}
.btn:hover:not(.inactive)>.btn-bottom,
.btn.active:not(.inactive)>.btn-bottom {
  z-index: 1;
  /* transform here */
}
```

(using nested conditional selectors to ensure all animations at same DOM, but different z-index levels run/complete properly)?

(Sorry about title length. No rep to create styled-components tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:hover:not(.inactive) > &, .active:not(.inactive) > &` works as (Sass) selectors.

Use with caution. Something like `.active &` could have side-effects in cases where multiple parents have the conditional classes (`.active` and `.inactive` here). An alternative would then be to [pass React props to descendants for conditional styling with `styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/tips-and-tricks.md#component-adjustments).

Answered on gitter by geleen (maintainer). Added here for completion and google-fu.